# How to make an input field as wide as possible inside a menu item in a top menu using semantic-ui-react

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have a header for my app. And it is a menu with many items. I have a menu.item which wraps an input field (its purpose is to search the given input site-wide). I want that menu.item to be as wide as the remaining space with input field as its children. My problem is very similar to [this](http://forums.semantic-ui.com/t/how-to-make-menu-item-100-width/131) visually. And yes, I have tried fluid prop in many permutations, unfortunately it did not help. Any help or insight on this problem? My Sample code is below and related codepen is [here](https://codepen.io/milkers/pen/EEyxGx).

```
<Menu inverted={true} fixed="top" size="small" color="violet">

  <Menu.Item as="a" header={true} >
    <Icon inverted={true} size="big" name="image" />
  </Menu.Item>

  <Container fluid={true}>
    <Menu.Item >
      <Input
        inverted={true}
        transparent={true}
        icon="search"
        iconPosition="left"
        placeholder="Search.."
      />
    </Menu.Item>
  </Container>

  <Menu.Item as="a" header={true} position="right">
    <Icon inverted={true} size="big" name="mail" />
  </Menu.Item>

</Menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantic UI uses flexbox styles on their responsive menu. This not as much of a Semantic UI React issue as it is a CSS issue. I do not believe there is a class that exists in Semantic UI styles to make a menu item grow. You'll have to solve this with CSS. It only requires one change.

The `Menu` is `display:flex` in CSS. The `Menu.Item` components are all children. The one with the search inside should have this added as an inline style: `style={{ flexGrow: 2 }}`

You also don't need the `Container` component. Here's everything:

```
<Menu inverted={true} fixed="top" size="small" color="violet">
  <Menu.Item as="a" header={true}>
    <Icon inverted={true} size="big" name="image" />
  </Menu.Item>

  <Menu.Item style={{ flexGrow: 2 }}>
    <Input
      inverted={true}
      transparent={true}
      icon="search"
      iconPosition="left"
      placeholder="Search..."
    />
  </Menu.Item>

  <Menu.Item as="a" header={true} position="right">
    <Icon inverted={true} size="big" name="mail" />
  </Menu.Item>
</Menu>
```

And here is a working codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/5x0x6ppm3k